# Setting DefaultStyleKey results in "ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm configuring a base page for my mobile application to have a couple additional boolean dependency properties to activate or deactivate some universal application bar menu items. Even though I'm registering these dependency properties with metadata about their default values, it doesn't seem that the setter for the value is ever called.

```
public class MyPageBase : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MyBasePage() {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyPageBase);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowSettingsMenuItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ShowSettingsMenuItem",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyPageBase),
        new PropertyMetadata(true, ShowSettingsMenuItemChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowLogoutMenuItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ShowLogoutMenuItem",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyPageBase),
        new PropertyMetadata(true, ShowLogoutMenuItemChanged));
}
```

I assumed then that I need to create a default "theme" for the page that sets these two properties to their values. I created a Themes folder and a Generic.xaml file inside with its build action set to Page. I then defined a very simple style targeting the page type that set the two properties to the default values in their metadata.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyApplication.View">
    <Style TargetType="view:MyPageBase">
        <Setter Property="ShowLogoutMenuItem" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ShowSettingsMenuItem" Value="True" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

However, when the first line in the base page's constructor is hit, the following exception is raised:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.

I've inspected the compiled library in ILSpy, and the Resources folder does contain a g.resources folder with all of the XAML files from the project, including one for themes/generic.xaml. What needs to be done to correctly initialize the default value of these dependency properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setter method will only be invoked when you explicitly change the value of a property. Setting a default value won't trigger it. If your properties affect UI elements, such as in your case, usually you would invoke the method that does the UI updates by overriding `OnApplyTemplate()` method for a user control.

However, since yours is a `PhoneApplicationPage` you can call your UI update method to show/hide the menus in your `Loaded` event. The values of the properties will be the same as the default values you set, which in your case was set to true.

Comment: Seems about right. It wasn't so much that the setter wasn't getting called, but instead my "change" function didn't accomplish anything since the value wasn't seen as changing from the default. I decided to test the booleans and run initialization once for true values on load.